# Software that can extract tables from PDF files

Tags: pdf, microsoft-excel, table

I often receive table data in PDF files. I want to be able to get that into MS Excel in a tabular format but it often comes out strangely when I copy-paste.

I want to be able to get tables out of PDF and into MS Excel while maintaining their structure.

Comment: If an answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 6):

Use [pdftables.com](https://pdftables.com/).

Sample input:

[image: sample input]

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: https://www.pdftoexcelonline.com/ also works.

Comment: @LShaver nice one! You should post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

[ABLE2EXTRACT PDF CONVERTER](http://www.investintech.com/prod_a2e.htm#prettyPhoto) does this brilliantly well. You can check demo video on their page. The thing I love about this software is (and I think its unique to this product alone):

1. You can just select an area from a page (a table in our case) on PDF and ask it to convert.
2. While converting it gives us two options: Automatic or Manual (I just love this). We can guide the software in recognizing proper columns and rows of the table.
3. After conversion it takes care of Number formatting too.

They have a [free online converter too for casual users](http://www.investintech.com/able2extract.html).
Here is a sample:

**In a PDF page:**
[image]

**After Automatic conversion:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [PDFGenie](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfgenie/).

This [blog post](https://blog.pdftron.com/2014/03/02/table-extraction-and-pdf-to-xml-with-pdfgenie/) goes over the product in more detail.

Sample input and output are in the [download](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfgenie/downloads.html).

The output is XHTML, so you would have to do some post processing to get something you could pass to Excel.

Answer (score -2):

Try using [Foxit PhantomPDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/). Be careful though, if the PDF contain text outside the table, it will be aligned to the left.

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an input/output sample like in Andrea's answer? Thanks!