# Convert PDF to text, preserving tables

Tags: pdf, document-converter, plain-text, table

What's the best software to convert a PDF file to text preserving its tables?

The tables might be converted into `__` or `---`; doesn't matter but I want to preserve them.

Comment: See also: [Software that can extract tables from PDF files](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34268/60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PDFGenie**](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfgenie/index.html) by PDFTron has very strong table detection/extraction. It outputs to HTML tables.

The blog post [*Table extraction and PDF to XML with PDFGenie*](https://blog.pdftron.com/2014/03/02/table-extraction-and-pdf-to-xml-with-pdfgenie/) explains the product in more detail.

You can [download the trial command line tool here](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfgenie/downloads.html).

Comment: Do you have any idea how much a licence can be?