# Extract table from PDF offline, on a computer where I can not install anything, but where VBA is available

Tags: pdf, offline, automation, data-extraction, vba

I need advice if/how the following is feasible. I am working on a computer, which does have Excel 2013 but no Adobe Acrobat installed. No third party software is to be installed or used.

Now I want to read / extract data from a PDF (imagine it has selectable text and not just images in it) and copy that content to Excel. Are there any built-in PDF libraries to do this and to automate this process? I thought of a VBA script. But all I could find via Google were solutions using Adobe libraries or other third party software. Maybe this has changed over the recent years. So what do you think?

Best regards

Comment: Do you need a program or a library, or any is fine? For instance, if your goal is to program a tool that has this feature, then a standalone program will probably not fit your need. Thanks!

Comment: If a tool is OK for you, then here are your answers: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34268/software-that-can-extract-tables-from-pdf-files :-)

Comment: Yes, it's still not clear to me why you don't use another PDF viewer. MUST you do this programmatically (if so, use Python, rather than VBA)?

Comment: @all: Thanks for your replies so far.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul: I must admit that I am not sure how to answer this. But I will try. There is a PDF coming in via mail on a regular basis. It includes a list of topics. These topics have to be transferred to an Excel spreadsheet. And I would like to automate this process so that I just drop the PDF in the same folder as the spreadsheet, click on a button and then it does the rest. Does this explanation help?

Comment: @Mawg: I am not allowed to install anything or code anything using resources which are not already available on the computer. Python is not installed, but VBA is accessible through MS Office.

Comment: @all: As some of the information in the PDF are confidential I cannot use a webservice either.

Comment: @all: And one more thing. When I have the list copied to Excel, this is not the end. Then further steps will be applied like creating an entire folder tree on a hard disk drive and so on. Therefore, extracting the information is only the first step.

Comment: I feel your pain. I am also not allowed to install anything. I push it a bit by downloading portable versions – making sure to use only software that is free for commercial use. I would recommend PDF eXchange Viewer. I use AutoIt to automate things in Windows as it can handle things that VBA cannot, and could do everything you want to do. I searched & see that there are portable versions, so this seems like the way to go. AutoIt is very Basic-like, so you will be up to speed very quickly. It is also well documented and has good code examples.

Comment: @Mawg: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. Nevertheless, is there a way to do this with VBA and built-in tools? I think that MSO must have some pdf libraries as it can read and write PDFs for a while now.

Comment: If you can read & write PFDs then you have your answer and, sorry, but i don't understand why the question

Comment: I don't know how to use that in VBA in order to extract information from a pdf.

Comment: Does anyone have another suggestion?